# Sorting array with object having numbers and characters

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array which looks like this:

```
  serials = [ serial : 8H51495999, material : 17, status: 01
              serial : 8H51495143, material : 17, status: 01
              serial : 8Z51495143, material : 17, status: 01 ]
```

I need to sort it by serial, so order would be

```
              serial : 8H51495143, material : 17, status: 01
              serial : 8H51495999, material : 17, status: 01
              serial : 8Z51495143, material : 17, status: 01
```

How can I achieve that?
Thank you,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you have an array of objects and the values are strings, then you could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for the sorting callback with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
var serials = [{ serial : '8H51495999', material : '17', status: '01' }, { serial : '8H51495143', material : '17', status: '01' }, { serial : '8Z51495143', material : '17', status: '01' }];

serials.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.serial.localeCompare(b.serial);
});

console.log(serials);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example) in JS

```
serials.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.serial < b.serial) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.serial > b.) {
        return 1;
      }
      // a must be equal to b
      return 0;
    });
```